# @ on a mac keyboard (actually Logitech k750-mac)

Tags: keyboard, mac

I've been down this road before, but have forgotten how to type an "@" from the keyboard. Trying to run raspberrypi. I currently get an odd character.

Comment: it isn't Shift+2 ?

Comment: No, but got it figured out. It is actually Shift+", and the Shift+2 is ".